# yii booster Datepicker not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii

I am using the yii booster bootstrap, but datepicker is not working. I also found bootstrap-datepicker.js is not registering in the correct path.

This is the error I get:

`http://localhost/assets/js/bootstrap.datepicker.js?_=1357902515857`

here instead of `http://localhost/**myproject**/assets/js/bootstrap.datepicker.js?_=1357902515857`

It should be in myproject/assests.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you register this file to the yii::app()? `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScriptFile`. Also try deleting all files and folders in `assets` because there might be a cache problem

Comment: Registering is done automatically when the datepicker field is encountered. ITs not being done manually. As well i deleted all assets files and tried but of no use..

Comment: What code are you using to generate the widget? because the original Yii Booster only adds styling, no extra js http://yii-booster.clevertech.biz/jquery.html#datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue by adding on the top the page.

```
    Yii::app()->bootstrap->registerAssetCss('bootstrap-datepicker.css');
    Yii::app()->bootstrap->registerAssetJs('bootstrap.datepicker.js');
```

Answer (score -1):

The Yii booster datepicker uses CJuiDatePicker, a zii widget included with the framework.

You should use the widget to create the datepicker field and not the normal bootstrap/jquery way.